# If $f(x) = (x+c)!$ and $g(x) = (ax+c)!$, how can I write $g(x)$ based on $f(x)$?

Tags: factorial, gamma-function

Consider $f(x) = (x+c)!$ and $g(x) = (ax+c)!$, where $a, x, c \geq 0$. Is there any way I can write $g(x)$ based on $f(x)$. I mean if I can write $g(x) = f(x)r(a, x)$, what would $r(a, x)$ be like?

In other words:
$g(ax+c)! = (ax+c)\times(ax+c-1)\times(ax+c-2)\times\dots\times(x+c+1)\times(x+c)!$

What I am looking for is a straightforward expression for $r(a,x)$:

$r(a,x) = (ax+c)\times(ax+c-1)\times(ax+c-2)\times\dots\times(x+c+1)$.

So, you can think of it as:

$r(a,x) = (ax+c)! - (x+c)!$ where $a > 1$. But I need something for $r(a,x)$ without the use of factorial.

Comment: $g(x)=f(ax)$ ???

Comment: By, e.g., $(x+c)!$ do you mean $\Gamma(x+c+1)$?  If so, why not try a few values for $x$ and $a$?  See if your formula makes sense.

Comment: But even for factorials...do you think that $\frac {n!}{(an)!}$ is independent of $n$?

Comment: @lulu You are right. I did correct it now. What I want is to know what is $r(a,x)$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I know what you mean. But what I need it to have something on the right side including $f(x)$. I have revised the question.

Comment: So, you want an expression for $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ which would not involve factorials, Gamma functions and the like?